# Put div within <td> tag behind table - z-index

Tags: css, html-table, z-index

I am trying to place a `<div>` inside a `<td>` tag, but want to move the div behind the table itself. This is somehow not working with normal z-index.

I know I could move it behind with a negative z-index, but this causes it to disappear behind my body, content, etc. I could also change their z-indexes to negative values but this causes other probems.

Is there any other way to solve what I am trying to do?
Basicly I want the `<div>` with the converted Dollar price to appear from behind the table on hover over the `<tr>`. Before it should not be visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/n0cvdhs9/

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>London</td><td>Rome</td><td>300€<div>=330$</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris</td><td>Madrid</td><td>200€<div>=320$</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table
```

CSS

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100
}

table, tbody, tr, td {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}





/* Just some styling nvm */

table {
    background: lightblue;
}

td { position: relative; padding: 5px 15px; }

div {
    background: lightgrey;
    width: 40px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
}
tr:hover div { 
    right: -40px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using z-indexes? Just do show and hide (not that this is necessarily good UX).

Comment: Because I want it to have a move in effect from left to right, from behind the € price and i would try to achieve this with CSS only.

Comment: So do that. You're not going to be able to put it behind its own parent, but you also haven't identified any reason that you need to do so.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am not sure how to achieve this because the div is always over the td. But I want to move it in form behind the td.

Comment: The point is: don't do that. What you are describing doesn't require you to use z-indexes. Moving from left to right doesn't have anything to do with a-indexes. Use show, hide, and position. In any case, your question is probably going to be closed because you haven't posted all of the relevant code.

Comment: Sorry maybe I missunderstand oyu, or oyu missunderstood me. I want the converted price to be moved in from left to right, form non-visible to visible. For this it has to be from behind the table or it will cover the other price. If i set it on hide or whatevr i can get a move in effect.

Comment: I understand perfectly what you are saying. I am telling you this is not how you do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the z-index on the parent of the parent and set negative z-index on child to hide the div. http://jsfiddle.net/o4x6p4qd/

Basically this:

```css
tr {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

td {
    position: relative;
    z-index: initial;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is actually what I did so far.
But the problem with this is that it makes it disappear behind my body, #content div, etc. This again can be solved by changing their value to a lower negative z-index but this causes further z-index problems.
I do look for an alternative approch.

Comment: Maybe you can try using `opacity` instead of `z-index` to (more-or-less) mimic the functionality without the headaches that come with the use of `z-index`es?

Answer (score 0):

One really easy way to do it WITHOUT the z-index would be to change the color of the font when the cursor hovers over it. I tried myself to do it using the z-index and it didn't work :(